# Styled-components get props value to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Hello stackoverflowers

I was wondering if it's possible to get the value of a `styled-component` props into a javascript variable.

Example

```
<CardBox Columns="3">
```

What I wanted to do is :

```
var Columns = props => props.Columns;
var ColumnCount;

for (var i = 0; i < Columns; i++) {
    ColumnCount = ColumnCount + "Auto ";
}

const CardBox = styled.div`
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: ${ColumnCount};
`;
```

But the variable Columns seems to be set to :

```
function (props) {
    return props.Columns;
}
```

And not '3' as I hoped :)

Hope somebody can guide me in the right direction, if possible.

Comment: Am I correct - you want to pass different `columns` props to multiple `<CardBox />` components?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, i want to use the column props to define the "grid-template-colums: auto auto auto" as in the example. if that makes any sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what you are trying to accomplish is totally normal and a lot of people try to use.

You mainly try to pass properties like this:

```
const CardBox = styled.div`
 width: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
 background: blue;
 height: ${props => props.columns}px; <-- as an example if we need pixels

 //we use props named columns as you will see below
`;


<CardBox columns={i} /> <-- how you pass to a styled component
```

In your case you will probably need to loop all your components and pass the parameter as you were doing and just render it, everything should be fine.

I made a simple codesanbox to try it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/21v3ql84kj

If you want a documentation part of property passing: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props

Good luck!

Comment: I think I wrote my question wrong :) (1st time poster), but i've made a [CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/8zpv5z7jql](https://codesandbox.io/s/8zpv5z7jql), of what im trying to achieve, so it probally makes better sense,  i made a few commnts in the code, so i hope my question makes betetr sense

Comment: Oh, no problem! I think I understood it: https://codesandbox.io/s/mjv3o3rr9p . You can just take it as a prop from another component and return all the children in the container.

Comment: Good to hear it helped!